# XBindkeys and Mouse key's giving keyboard numbers (0-9)

Tags: linux, fedora, mouse, xdotool, xbindkeys

#### XINPUT

```
➜ xinput --list          
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ TypeMatrix.com USB Keyboard               id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Razer Razer Naga Epic Chroma Dock         id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Razer Razer Naga Epic Chroma Dock         id=17   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Penlic Wireless Mouse R2                  id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ASUS ROG SPATHA                           id=18   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ASUS ROG SPATHA                           id=21   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Creative Technology Ltd. Live! Cam inPerson HD VF0720 id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Penlic Wireless Mouse R2                  id=19   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Live! Cam inPerson HD VF0720: L           id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ TypeMatrix.com USB Keyboard               id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ TypeMatrix.com USB Keyboard               id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Razer Razer Naga Epic Chroma Dock         id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Razer Razer Naga Epic Chroma Dock         id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ ASUS ROG SPATHA                           id=20   [slave  keyboard (3)]

➜ xinput --query-state 18
2 classes :
ButtonClass
    button[1]=up
    button[2]=up
    button[3]=up
    button[4]=up
    button[5]=up
    button[6]=up
    button[7]=up
ValuatorClass Mode=Relative Proximity=In
    valuator[0]=0
    valuator[1]=0
    valuator[2]=0
    valuator[3]=0

~ 
➜ xinput --query-state 21
2 classes :
ButtonClass
    button[1]=up
    button[2]=up
    button[3]=up
    button[4]=up
    button[5]=up
    button[6]=up
    button[7]=up
    button[8]=up
    button[9]=up
ValuatorClass Mode=Relative Proximity=In
    valuator[0]=1225
    valuator[1]=1431
    valuator[2]=0
    valuator[3]=5880

➜ xinput --query-state 20
1 class :
KeyClass
    key[0]=up
    key[1]=up
    key[2]=up
    key[3]=up
    key[4]=up
    key[5]=up
    key[6]=up
    key[7]=up
    key[8]=up
    key[9]=up
    key[10]=up
    key[11]=up
    key[12]=up
    key[13]=up
    key[14]=up
    key[15]=up
    key[16]=up
    key[17]=up
    key[18]=up
    key[19]=up
    key[20]=up
    key[21]=up
    key[22]=up
    key[23]=up
    key[24]=up
    key[25]=up
    key[26]=up
    key[27]=up
    key[28]=up
    key[29]=up
    key[30]=up
    key[31]=up
    key[32]=up
    key[33]=up
    key[34]=up
    key[35]=up
    key[36]=up
    key[37]=up
    key[38]=up
    key[39]=up
    key[40]=up
    key[41]=up
    key[42]=up
    key[43]=up
    key[44]=up
    key[45]=up
    key[46]=up
    key[47]=up
    key[48]=up
    key[49]=up
    key[50]=up
    key[51]=up
    key[52]=up
    key[53]=up
    key[54]=up
    key[55]=up
    key[56]=up
    key[57]=up
    key[58]=up
    key[59]=up
    key[60]=up
    key[61]=up
    key[62]=up
    key[63]=up
    key[64]=up
    key[65]=up
    key[66]=up
    key[67]=up
    key[68]=up
    key[69]=up
    key[70]=up
    key[71]=up
    key[72]=up
    key[73]=up
    key[74]=up
    key[75]=up
    key[76]=up
    key[77]=up
    key[78]=up
    key[79]=up
    key[80]=up
    key[81]=up
    key[82]=up
    key[83]=up
    key[84]=up
    key[85]=up
    key[86]=up
    key[87]=up
    key[88]=up
    key[89]=up
    key[90]=up
    key[91]=up
    key[92]=up
    key[93]=up
    key[94]=up
    key[95]=up
    key[96]=up
    key[97]=up
    key[98]=up
    key[99]=up
    key[100]=up
    key[101]=up
    key[102]=up
    key[103]=up
    key[104]=up
    key[105]=up
    key[106]=up
    key[107]=up
    key[108]=up
    key[109]=up
    key[110]=up
    key[111]=up
    key[112]=up
    key[113]=up
    key[114]=up
    key[115]=up
    key[116]=up
    key[117]=up
    key[118]=up
    key[119]=up
    key[120]=up
    key[121]=up
    key[122]=up
    key[123]=up
    key[124]=up
    key[125]=up
    key[126]=up
    key[127]=up
    key[128]=up
    key[129]=up
    key[130]=up
    key[131]=up
    key[132]=up
    key[133]=up
    key[134]=up
    key[135]=up
    key[136]=up
    key[137]=up
    key[138]=up
    key[139]=up
    key[140]=up
    key[141]=up
    key[142]=up
    key[143]=up
    key[144]=up
    key[145]=up
    key[146]=up
    key[147]=up
    key[148]=up
    key[149]=up
    key[150]=up
    key[151]=up
    key[152]=up
    key[153]=up
    key[154]=up
    key[155]=up
    key[156]=up
    key[157]=up
    key[158]=up
    key[159]=up
    key[160]=up
    key[161]=up
    key[162]=up
    key[163]=up
    key[164]=up
    key[165]=up
    key[166]=up
    key[167]=up
    key[168]=up
    key[169]=up
    key[170]=up
    key[171]=up
    key[172]=up
    key[173]=up
    key[174]=up
    key[175]=up
    key[176]=up
    key[177]=up
    key[178]=up
    key[179]=up
    key[180]=up
    key[181]=up
    key[182]=up
    key[183]=up
    key[184]=up
    key[185]=up
    key[186]=up
    key[187]=up
    key[188]=up
    key[189]=up
    key[190]=up
    key[191]=up
    key[192]=up
    key[193]=up
    key[194]=up
    key[195]=up
    key[196]=up
    key[197]=up
    key[198]=up
    key[199]=up
    key[200]=up
    key[201]=up
    key[202]=up
    key[203]=up
    key[204]=up
    key[205]=up
    key[206]=up
    key[207]=up
    key[208]=up
    key[209]=up
    key[210]=up
    key[211]=up
    key[212]=up
    key[213]=up
    key[214]=up
    key[215]=up
    key[216]=up
    key[217]=up
    key[218]=up
    key[219]=up
    key[220]=up
    key[221]=up
    key[222]=up
    key[223]=up
    key[224]=up
    key[225]=up
    key[226]=up
    key[227]=up
    key[228]=up
    key[229]=up
    key[230]=up
    key[231]=up
    key[232]=up
    key[233]=up
    key[234]=up
    key[235]=up
    key[236]=up
    key[237]=up
    key[238]=up
    key[239]=up
    key[240]=up
    key[241]=up
    key[242]=up
    key[243]=up
    key[244]=up
    key[245]=up
    key[246]=up
    key[247]=up
```

#### EVTEST

➜ evtest

```
No device specified, trying to scan all of /dev/input/event*
Not running as root, no devices may be available.
Available devices:
/dev/input/event0:  Power Button
/dev/input/event1:  Power Button
/dev/input/event2:  ASUS ROG SPATHA
/dev/input/event3:  ASUS ROG SPATHA
/dev/input/event4:  Razer Razer Naga Epic Chroma Dock
/dev/input/event5:  Razer Razer Naga Epic Chroma Dock
/dev/input/event6:  Razer Razer Naga Epic Chroma Dock
/dev/input/event7:  Penlic Wireless Mouse R2
/dev/input/event8:  TypeMatrix.com USB Keyboard
/dev/input/event9:  TypeMatrix.com USB Keyboard
/dev/input/event10: Kensington Expert Wireless TB
/dev/input/event11: Creative Technology Ltd. Live! Cam inPerson HD VF0720
/dev/input/event12: HDA Intel PCH Front Line Out
/dev/input/event13: HDA Intel PCH Line Out
/dev/input/event14: HDA Intel PCH Front Headphone
/dev/input/event15: Live! Cam inPerson HD VF0720: L
/dev/input/event16: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=3
/dev/input/event17: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=7
/dev/input/event18: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=8
/dev/input/event19: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=9


Select the device event number [0-19]: 2
Input driver version is 1.0.1
Input device ID: bus 0x3 vendor 0xb05 product 0x1824 version 0x111
Input device name: "ASUS ROG SPATHA"
Supported events:
  Event type 0 (EV_SYN)
  Event type 1 (EV_KEY)
    Event code 272 (BTN_LEFT)
    Event code 273 (BTN_RIGHT)
    Event code 274 (BTN_MIDDLE)
    Event code 275 (BTN_SIDE)
    Event code 276 (BTN_EXTRA)
  Event type 2 (EV_REL)
    Event code 0 (REL_X)
    Event code 1 (REL_Y)
    Event code 6 (REL_HWHEEL)
    Event code 8 (REL_WHEEL)
  Event type 4 (EV_MSC)
    Event code 4 (MSC_SCAN)
Properties:
Testing ... (interrupt to exit)

Select the device event number [0-19]: 3
Input driver version is 1.0.1
Input device ID: bus 0x3 vendor 0xb05 product 0x1824 version 0x111
Input device name: "ASUS ROG SPATHA"
Supported events:
  Event type 0 (EV_SYN)
  Event type 1 (EV_KEY)
    Event code 1 (KEY_ESC)
    Event code 2 (KEY_1)
    Event code 3 (KEY_2)
    Event code 4 (KEY_3)
    Event code 5 (KEY_4)
    Event code 6 (KEY_5)
    Event code 7 (KEY_6)
    Event code 8 (KEY_7)
    Event code 9 (KEY_8)
    Event code 10 (KEY_9)
    Event code 11 (KEY_0)
    Event code 12 (KEY_MINUS)
    Event code 13 (KEY_EQUAL)
    Event code 14 (KEY_BACKSPACE)
    Event code 15 (KEY_TAB)
    Event code 16 (KEY_Q)
    Event code 17 (KEY_W)
    Event code 18 (KEY_E)
    Event code 19 (KEY_R)
    Event code 20 (KEY_T)
    Event code 21 (KEY_Y)
    Event code 22 (KEY_U)
    Event code 23 (KEY_I)
    Event code 24 (KEY_O)
    Event code 25 (KEY_P)
    Event code 26 (KEY_LEFTBRACE)
    Event code 27 (KEY_RIGHTBRACE)
    Event code 28 (KEY_ENTER)
    Event code 29 (KEY_LEFTCTRL)
    Event code 30 (KEY_A)
    Event code 31 (KEY_S)
    Event code 32 (KEY_D)
    Event code 33 (KEY_F)
    Event code 34 (KEY_G)
    Event code 35 (KEY_H)
    Event code 36 (KEY_J)
    Event code 37 (KEY_K)
    Event code 38 (KEY_L)
    Event code 39 (KEY_SEMICOLON)
    Event code 40 (KEY_APOSTROPHE)
    Event code 41 (KEY_GRAVE)
    Event code 42 (KEY_LEFTSHIFT)
    Event code 43 (KEY_BACKSLASH)
    Event code 44 (KEY_Z)
    Event code 45 (KEY_X)
    Event code 46 (KEY_C)
    Event code 47 (KEY_V)
    Event code 48 (KEY_B)
    Event code 49 (KEY_N)
    Event code 50 (KEY_M)
    Event code 51 (KEY_COMMA)
    Event code 52 (KEY_DOT)
    Event code 53 (KEY_SLASH)
    Event code 54 (KEY_RIGHTSHIFT)
    Event code 55 (KEY_KPASTERISK)
    Event code 56 (KEY_LEFTALT)
    Event code 57 (KEY_SPACE)
    Event code 58 (KEY_CAPSLOCK)
    Event code 59 (KEY_F1)
    Event code 60 (KEY_F2)
    Event code 61 (KEY_F3)
    Event code 62 (KEY_F4)
    Event code 63 (KEY_F5)
    Event code 64 (KEY_F6)
    Event code 65 (KEY_F7)
    Event code 66 (KEY_F8)
    Event code 67 (KEY_F9)
    Event code 68 (KEY_F10)
    Event code 69 (KEY_NUMLOCK)
    Event code 70 (KEY_SCROLLLOCK)
    Event code 71 (KEY_KP7)
    Event code 72 (KEY_KP8)
    Event code 73 (KEY_KP9)
    Event code 74 (KEY_KPMINUS)
    Event code 75 (KEY_KP4)
    Event code 76 (KEY_KP5)
    Event code 77 (KEY_KP6)
    Event code 78 (KEY_KPPLUS)
    Event code 79 (KEY_KP1)
    Event code 80 (KEY_KP2)
    Event code 81 (KEY_KP3)
    Event code 82 (KEY_KP0)
    Event code 83 (KEY_KPDOT)
    Event code 85 (KEY_ZENKAKUHANKAKU)
    Event code 86 (KEY_102ND)
    Event code 87 (KEY_F11)
    Event code 88 (KEY_F12)
    Event code 89 (KEY_RO)
    Event code 90 (KEY_KATAKANA)
    Event code 91 (KEY_HIRAGANA)
    Event code 92 (KEY_HENKAN)
    Event code 93 (KEY_KATAKANAHIRAGANA)
    Event code 94 (KEY_MUHENKAN)
    Event code 95 (KEY_KPJPCOMMA)
    Event code 96 (KEY_KPENTER)
    Event code 97 (KEY_RIGHTCTRL)
    Event code 98 (KEY_KPSLASH)
    Event code 99 (KEY_SYSRQ)
    Event code 100 (KEY_RIGHTALT)
    Event code 102 (KEY_HOME)
    Event code 103 (KEY_UP)
    Event code 104 (KEY_PAGEUP)
    Event code 105 (KEY_LEFT)
    Event code 106 (KEY_RIGHT)
    Event code 107 (KEY_END)
    Event code 108 (KEY_DOWN)
    Event code 109 (KEY_PAGEDOWN)
    Event code 110 (KEY_INSERT)
    Event code 111 (KEY_DELETE)
    Event code 113 (KEY_MUTE)
    Event code 114 (KEY_VOLUMEDOWN)
    Event code 115 (KEY_VOLUMEUP)
    Event code 116 (KEY_POWER)
    Event code 117 (KEY_KPEQUAL)
    Event code 119 (KEY_PAUSE)
    Event code 121 (KEY_KPCOMMA)
    Event code 122 (KEY_HANGUEL)
    Event code 123 (KEY_HANJA)
    Event code 124 (KEY_YEN)
    Event code 125 (KEY_LEFTMETA)
    Event code 126 (KEY_RIGHTMETA)
    Event code 127 (KEY_COMPOSE)
    Event code 128 (KEY_STOP)
    Event code 129 (KEY_AGAIN)
    Event code 130 (KEY_PROPS)
    Event code 131 (KEY_UNDO)
    Event code 132 (KEY_FRONT)
    Event code 133 (KEY_COPY)
    Event code 134 (KEY_OPEN)
    Event code 135 (KEY_PASTE)
    Event code 136 (KEY_FIND)
    Event code 137 (KEY_CUT)
    Event code 138 (KEY_HELP)
    Event code 139 (KEY_MENU)
    Event code 140 (KEY_CALC)
    Event code 142 (KEY_SLEEP)
    Event code 144 (KEY_FILE)
    Event code 150 (KEY_WWW)
    Event code 152 (KEY_SCREENLOCK)
    Event code 155 (KEY_MAIL)
    Event code 156 (KEY_BOOKMARKS)
    Event code 158 (KEY_BACK)
    Event code 159 (KEY_FORWARD)
    Event code 161 (KEY_EJECTCD)
    Event code 163 (KEY_NEXTSONG)
    Event code 164 (KEY_PLAYPAUSE)
    Event code 165 (KEY_PREVIOUSSONG)
    Event code 166 (KEY_STOPCD)
    Event code 167 (KEY_RECORD)
    Event code 168 (KEY_REWIND)
    Event code 169 (KEY_PHONE)
    Event code 171 (KEY_CONFIG)
    Event code 172 (KEY_HOMEPAGE)
    Event code 173 (KEY_REFRESH)
    Event code 174 (KEY_EXIT)
    Event code 176 (KEY_EDIT)
    Event code 177 (KEY_SCROLLUP)
    Event code 178 (KEY_SCROLLDOWN)
    Event code 179 (KEY_KPLEFTPAREN)
    Event code 180 (KEY_KPRIGHTPAREN)
    Event code 181 (KEY_NEW)
    Event code 182 (KEY_REDO)
    Event code 183 (KEY_F13)
    Event code 184 (KEY_F14)
    Event code 185 (KEY_F15)
    Event code 186 (KEY_F16)
    Event code 187 (KEY_F17)
    Event code 188 (KEY_F18)
    Event code 189 (KEY_F19)
    Event code 190 (KEY_F20)
    Event code 191 (KEY_F21)
    Event code 192 (KEY_F22)
    Event code 193 (KEY_F23)
    Event code 194 (KEY_F24)
    Event code 206 (KEY_CLOSE)
    Event code 207 (KEY_PLAY)
    Event code 208 (KEY_FASTFORWARD)
    Event code 209 (KEY_BASSBOOST)
    Event code 210 (KEY_PRINT)
    Event code 212 (KEY_CAMERA)
    Event code 216 (KEY_CHAT)
    Event code 217 (KEY_SEARCH)
    Event code 219 (KEY_FINANCE)
    Event code 223 (KEY_CANCEL)
    Event code 224 (KEY_BRIGHTNESSDOWN)
    Event code 225 (KEY_BRIGHTNESSUP)
    Event code 228 (KEY_KBDILLUMTOGGLE)
    Event code 231 (KEY_SEND)
    Event code 232 (KEY_REPLY)
    Event code 233 (KEY_FORWARDMAIL)
    Event code 234 (KEY_SAVE)
    Event code 235 (KEY_DOCUMENTS)
    Event code 240 (KEY_UNKNOWN)
    Event code 241 (KEY_VIDEO_NEXT)
    Event code 244 (KEY_BRIGHTNESS_ZERO)
    Event code 256 (BTN_0)
    Event code 353 (KEY_SELECT)
    Event code 354 (KEY_GOTO)
    Event code 358 (KEY_INFO)
    Event code 362 (KEY_PROGRAM)
    Event code 366 (KEY_PVR)
    Event code 370 (KEY_SUBTITLE)
    Event code 372 (KEY_ZOOM)
    Event code 374 (KEY_KEYBOARD)
    Event code 376 (KEY_PC)
    Event code 377 (KEY_TV)
    Event code 378 (KEY_TV2)
    Event code 379 (KEY_VCR)
    Event code 380 (KEY_VCR2)
    Event code 381 (KEY_SAT)
    Event code 383 (KEY_CD)
    Event code 384 (KEY_TAPE)
    Event code 386 (KEY_TUNER)
    Event code 387 (KEY_PLAYER)
    Event code 389 (KEY_DVD)
    Event code 392 (KEY_AUDIO)
    Event code 393 (KEY_VIDEO)
    Event code 396 (KEY_MEMO)
    Event code 397 (KEY_CALENDAR)
    Event code 398 (KEY_RED)
    Event code 399 (KEY_GREEN)
    Event code 400 (KEY_YELLOW)
    Event code 401 (KEY_BLUE)
    Event code 402 (KEY_CHANNELUP)
    Event code 403 (KEY_CHANNELDOWN)
    Event code 405 (KEY_LAST)
    Event code 407 (KEY_NEXT)
    Event code 408 (KEY_RESTART)
    Event code 409 (KEY_SLOW)
    Event code 410 (KEY_SHUFFLE)
    Event code 412 (KEY_PREVIOUS)
    Event code 416 (KEY_VIDEOPHONE)
    Event code 417 (KEY_GAMES)
    Event code 418 (KEY_ZOOMIN)
    Event code 419 (KEY_ZOOMOUT)
    Event code 420 (KEY_ZOOMRESET)
    Event code 421 (KEY_WORDPROCESSOR)
    Event code 422 (KEY_EDITOR)
    Event code 423 (KEY_SPREADSHEET)
    Event code 424 (KEY_GRAPHICSEDITOR)
    Event code 425 (KEY_PRESENTATION)
    Event code 426 (KEY_DATABASE)
    Event code 427 (KEY_NEWS)
    Event code 428 (KEY_VOICEMAIL)
    Event code 429 (KEY_ADDRESSBOOK)
    Event code 430 (KEY_MESSENGER)
    Event code 431 (KEY_DISPLAYTOGGLE)
    Event code 432 (KEY_SPELLCHECK)
    Event code 433 (KEY_LOGOFF)
    Event code 439 (KEY_MEDIA_REPEAT)
    Event code 442 (KEY_IMAGES)
    Event code 576 (KEY_BUTTONCONFIG)
    Event code 577 (KEY_TASKMANAGER)
    Event code 578 (KEY_JOURNAL)
    Event code 579 (KEY_CONTROLPANEL)
    Event code 580 (KEY_APPSELECT)
    Event code 581 (KEY_SCREENSAVER)
    Event code 582 (KEY_VOICECOMMAND)
    Event code 592 (KEY_BRIGHTNESS_MIN)
    Event code 593 (KEY_BRIGHTNESS_MAX)
  Event type 2 (EV_REL)
    Event code 0 (REL_X)
    Event code 1 (REL_Y)
    Event code 6 (REL_HWHEEL)
  Event type 3 (EV_ABS)
    Event code 32 (ABS_VOLUME)
      Value      0
      Min        0
      Max      668
  Event type 4 (EV_MSC)
    Event code 4 (MSC_SCAN)
  Event type 17 (EV_LED)
    Event code 0 (LED_NUML) state 0
    Event code 1 (LED_CAPSL) state 0
    Event code 2 (LED_SCROLLL) state 0
    Event code 3 (LED_COMPOSE) state 0
    Event code 4 (LED_KANA) state 0
Key repeat handling:
  Repeat type 20 (EV_REP)
    Repeat code 0 (REP_DELAY)
      Value    250
    Repeat code 1 (REP_PERIOD)
      Value     33
Properties:
```

#### XBINDKEYS

I'm trying to assign "Ctrl-W" click to button's on the left side of Asus ROG SPATHA Mouse, they have the following key codes

```
➜ xbindkeys -k           
Press combination of keys or/and click under the window.
You can use one of the two lines after "NoCommand"
in $HOME/.xbindkeysrc to bind a key.
"(Scheme function)"
    m:0x0 + c:16
    7

~ 
➜ xbindkeys -k
Press combination of keys or/and click under the window.
You can use one of the two lines after "NoCommand"
in $HOME/.xbindkeysrc to bind a key.
"(Scheme function)"
    m:0x0 + c:19
    0
```

and inside the shell, they simply output numbers 0 & 7. At the same time it seems they don't have "mouse button" attached to them, because when I run

```
xev | grep button
```

I get no output when I click on these buttons, and some other buttons on the mouse got the mouse button assigned

```
➜ xev | grep button
534:ButtonPress event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x1a00001,
536:    state 0x0, button 1, same_screen YES
547:ButtonRelease event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x1a00001,
549:    state 0x100, button 1, same_screen YES
556:ButtonPress event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x1a00001,
558:    state 0x0, button 3, same_screen YES
569:ButtonRelease event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x1a00001,
571:    state 0x400, button 3, same_screen YES
578:ButtonPress event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x1a00001,
580:    state 0x0, button 9, same_screen YES
591:ButtonRelease event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x1a00001,
593:    state 0x0, button 9, same_screen YES
600:ButtonPress event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x1a00001,
602:    state 0x0, button 8, same_screen YES
613:ButtonRelease event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x1a00001,
615:    state 0x0, button 8, same_screen YES
626:ButtonPress event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x1a00001,
628:    state 0x0, button 2, same_screen YES
639:ButtonRelease event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x1a00001,
641:    state 0x200, button 2, same_screen YES
```

as you can see above I have mouse buttons 1,2,3, 8,9, but there are no 4,5,6,7 (mouse has total 9 clickable buttons)

#### Any ideas what can be done?

Comment: repeat `xinput --query-state` tests on device 20 and see what `evtest` detects on all 3 devices (18, 21 mouse devices, 20 kbd device).

Comment: Maybe a problem with driver software?

Comment: @quixotic added info about device 20 (in XINPUT section) and EVTEST output.

Comment: at a guess, those "buttons" are coming through on the keyboard interface and not the mouse, so `xev | grep Button` doesn't see them -- `xev` should show keypresses for them, and if you press each button while `evtest` is running on that device you should see the scancode coming across.  changing the configuration would be like customizing a keyboard -- a custom `hwdb` entry or XKB layout could setup a basic key.  i think you'd still need `xbindkeys` or `xdotool` or similar for a chord effect like `Ctrl+W`.

Comment: thanks @quixotic I'll try with custom keyboard layout for the mouse